# Tight layout not working in matplotlib while using geopandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some points and line using matplotlib in python. The plot is created as expected, however when I plot using pandas, the tight layout does not work. There is some horizontal padding.

Without Using Pandas:

[image: Without using Pandas]

With using Pandas
[image: With using Pandas]

Here is the code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 import geopandas as gpd
 import shapely
 import shapely.wkt

 np_points=np.array([[72.86009142, 29.64570243],
   [72.85274575, 29.78470986],
   [72.93887416, 29.71148897],
   [72.83244904, 29.75750026],
   [72.90035624, 29.70708829],
   [73.00605427, 29.80544062],
   [72.94799582, 29.67417403],
   [72.73562998, 29.4550647 ],
   [72.76805617, 29.69165799],
   [73.13370963, 29.69718494],
   [72.922815  , 29.77253796]])

  data={'gid': 1,
     'geometry': shapely.wkt.loads('MULTILINESTRING  ((72.8626261872615 
    29.6481953436182, 72.8635141595275 29.6481903937668), (72.8635141595275 
   29.6481903937668, 72.8643668607309 29.6481856405281))')
      }

 df=gpd.GeoDataFrame([data],crs='epsg:4326').set_index('gid')

 fig, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
 plt.ion()
 ##showing plot in full screen
 manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
 manager.window.showMaximized()

 ax.plot(np_points[1:,0], np_points[1:,1], 'ro',markersize=8,label ='A')
 ax.plot(np_points[[1,2]][:,0], np_points[[1,2]][:,1], 
 'ro',color='green',markersize=10,label ='B')

 df.plot(ax=ax,color='b',linestyle='-',linewidth=1)
```

Comment: Does it help to add `plt.tight_layout()` at the end instead of using `plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)`? Or to explicitly call `plt.show()` at the very end?

Comment: I tried both but same issue when plotting this line.

Comment: You might want to include some test data for x and y, and add the imports, to create a minimal viable example.  That would increase the chance of other people trying to reproduce your code.  Please confirm that you are using the latest pandas and matplotlib versions.  As pandas just creates a very thin layer towards matplotlib, the problem you describe is very unlikely.

Comment: I have added the sample data.

Comment: What environment are you using? Which matplotlib backend? (The default throws an error at `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'showMaximized'`.

Comment: I am using anaconda on Spyder.

Comment: Does removing the code to show the plot in full screen work? (the two lines ```manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()``` and ```manager.window.showMaximized()```)

Comment: Does not work either.